# Why is my BFS algo not returning expected shortest path?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am trying to code an algorithm which should find shortest transformation path from given **beginWord** to an **endWord**, such that one letter can be changed at a time.

**Test Case**

```
beginWord = "hit"

endWord = "cog"

wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
```

Expected Output is 5 as one of the shortest transformation can be following whose length is 5:

`"hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog"`

In my algorithm, I follow BFS using queue and for each word, I replace each of its letter with all alphabets starting from 'a' to 'z' and while doing so I check if resultant word exists in given dictionary i.e. the **wordList**.

If it does, then I push it into the queue, so it can be processed too just like the last word. Otherwise, next entry from queue is taken and so on until the queue is empty.

Now, my code given below returns `hit -> hot -> dot -> lot -> dog -> log -> cog`, which is a wrong output. This is mainly because of the wrong transformation of `dot` into `lot` as well as `dog`.

Both `lot` and `dog` and one letter different from `dot` and therefore they both get pushed to the queue and processed later which result into similar problem of double transformation of `lot` into `log` and `cog`.

Now, this clearly shows that I am missing some crucial point of BFS and shortest path hunt. How can I decide that I have to transform `dot` into `dog` instead of `lot` in order to make sure that I get to the expected target following a shortest path, provided that both are valid transformations of `dot`.

This will help me understand and fix my code.

```
var ladderLength = function(beginWord, endWord, wordList) {

    wordList = new Set(wordList);
    var str = [beginWord];

    var queue = [], distance = 0, i, j, len;
    len = beginWord.length;
    queue.push(beginWord);

    while (queue.length > 0) {
        var currentWord = queue.shift();
        if (currentWord === endWord) {
            console.log(str.join(" -> "));
            return distance + 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var tempCh = currentWord[i];
            for (j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j = String.fromCharCode(j.charCodeAt(0)+1)) {
                currentWord = currentWord.replaceAt(i,j);
                if (wordList.has(currentWord)) {
                    distance++;
                    wordList.delete(currentWord);
                    str.push(currentWord);
                    queue.push(currentWord);
                }
            }
            currentWord = currentWord.replaceAt(i, tempCh);

        }   
    }
    return 0;
};


String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the main issue in my understanding. Main problem was that at a given level which is distance 'd' from root level of tree, I can have multiple matches e.g. "lot" and "dog" were at same level as they were achieved by transforming "dot".

At each level, I have to exhaust the queue as otherwise the distance I calculate will become incorrect.

So, when I changed my code to following (see comment `Process all items in queue which contains words on same level` in the code), algorithm got better. Better at least for many test cases including the one given in this question.

Thank you all for reviewing the code. :)

var ladderLength = function(beginWord, endWord, wordList) {
        wordList = new Set(wordList);

```
    var queue = [], distance = 1, i, j, len;
    len = beginWord.length;
    queue.push(beginWord);

    while (queue.length > 0) {
        // Process all items in queue which contains words on same level
        for (var k=0; k<queue.length; k++) {
            var currentWord = queue.shift();
            if (currentWord === endWord) {
                return distance;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tempCh = currentWord[i];
                for (j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j = String.fromCharCode(j.charCodeAt(0)+1)) {
                    if (j !== tempCh) {
                        currentWord = currentWord.replaceAt(i,j);
                        if (wordList.has(currentWord)) {
                            wordList.delete(currentWord);
                            queue.push(currentWord);
                        }
                    }
                }
                currentWord = currentWord.replaceAt(i, tempCh);

            } 
        }
        distance++;
    }
    return 0;
};

String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some additional processing while transforming the string to get the correct output. Before replacing the letter, compare the character which will be replaced `(i)` with the character that will take it's place `(j)`.

Keep a flag variable `flag` for every iteration and check whether the new character `j` will be closer to the character at the corresponding position in the `EndWord`. If it is moving closer instead of going away (for example, 'd' vs 'l' for 'c' in cog), and exists in `WordList`, make the replacement and set `flag = true`. If another transformation is also possible with the same distance from the character, check for the flag, if true, skip it, otherwise make the transformation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I replace each of its letter with all alphabets

means you do way too many validity checks. 
I suggest the you replace each letter only with **valid** letters. For example i in "hit" can only be replaced with o of: "hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog". 
This will make the program more efficient and less error prone.

Comment: "lot" is in the wordList. It small case L. Also, not sure what you mean by h in "hot" can be replaced with o of "dot", "dog". There is no replacing required. "hot" needs to be transformed into another word such that you only change one letter at a time and that the resulting word exists in wordList.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited the post to fix it. Do you agree that `i in "hit" can only be replaced with o of: "hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"` ?

Comment: let's take a step back. "hit" can be changed only to a word which is one character different so for example: "ait", "bit",....,"zit" are all valid as they have only one character (the first one) different. Similarly, "hat", "hbt", "hct",....."hzt" are also one character different. And same for "hia", "hib", "hic",....."hiz". Out of all those options the valid ones are only those which exist in given wordList. Makes sense?

Comment: It does. My point is that given `wordList` h of hit can only be swapped with d l or c.  i of hit can only be replaced with o ......consider using only those letters when swapping, and not the entire alphabet

Comment: Sure, you are right, I guess. We can however have a very last wordList as well. In that case it may not make a difference. But I see what you are saying i.e. don't create all possible words. Instead, traverse through the wordList perhaps.